# check box in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net

I need help in check box my problem that when i select any one it gave me message

about my selection but when choose two of check box gave me the last choose of them why and what is the fix please [image]

Comment: If both 1 and 2 are checked, the first *three* if statements succeed and execute their contents - so the final assignment to Label5 wins. You may want to use `else if` instead?

Comment: Please type your code, and not place images

Comment: StringBuilder sbuserchoices = new StringBuilder();
       if (CheckBox1.Checked && CheckBox2.Checked)
        {
      sbuserchoices.Append(Label5.Text =(""));
        }
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            sbuserchoices.Append(Label5.Text = (""));
        }
        if (CheckBox2.Checked)
        {
            sbuserchoices.Append(Label5.Text = (" "));
        }
        if (CheckBox3.Checked)
        {
            sbuserchoices.Append(Label5.Text = (""));
        }
        if (CheckBox4.Checked)
        {
            sbuserchoices.Append(Label5.Text = (""));
        }

Comment: sorry i will type it

Comment: If i use .     (if)in the selection of the first and put else in the double select it will work?

Comment: Are you mean like.      If(checkbox1.ckecked)  {sbuserchoies.append(label5.text=("");       else.          If(checkbox1.checked&&checkbox2.checked){sbuserchoice.append(label5.text=("");

Comment: Its work thanks alot.all about else if

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your Append status is wrong.  Instead of appending, you are overwriting the current value.  Hence when you choose say two answers, the first is overwritten by the second.

I think the problem is with the syntax of your Append status.  Instead of:

Append(Label5.Text =("New Text"));

It should be something like:

Append(Label5.Text).Append("Your new text");

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: You say about if else.    You mean if i use the first choose in (if) and the double choose in else .it will be work